# How to insert multiple records to a table using PHP and Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to add multiple records to one form using php and mysqli.Here Is my code 
In the beginning of my php page I included database connection code here I have attached code to insert data but hen i submit button data wont insert into table.Can anyone help me to solve this ?

```
$test='TN000006-1,TN000006-2,TN000006-3,TN000006-4' ;
$numberChunks = explode(",", $test);

echo "First chunk = $numberChunks[0]<br />";
$insertbookcopy="insert into bookcopy('bookcopNo')values";
for($i=0;$i<$copy;$i++){
    echo  $numberChunks[$i];
    $insertbookcopy .="('$numberChunks[$i]',$titleNo)";
}
```

Comment: You have multiple errors and do no error checking. Removing my answer and voting to close.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm new to these languages can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
$test='TN000006-1,TN000006-2,TN000006-3,TN000006-4';
$numberChunks = explode(",", $test);
$copy = count($numberChunks); //not sure why you called it copy though

for($i=0;$i<$copy;$i++)
{
$insertbookcopy = "insert into bookcopy ('bookcopNo') values ('".$numberChunks[$i]."');";
echo $insertbookcopy;
echo "<br>";
$result = mysql_query($insertbookcopy);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but still data don't insert .

Comment: See edit - include the echo lines to see what you are getting.

Comment: @ Richard Griffiths finally code is working :)  thanks a lot for your help